# In or Out? Stack Exchange's Winter Bash 2012 Hat Dash

Tags: discussion

Should this site participate in Stack Exchange's Winter Bash 2012 '[Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/)'?

Basically your avatar can earn a special hat for performing certain actions.

[image]

Please vote on the below answers (feel free to leave any comments).

We have to opt-in by **28 November 2012**.

Comment: As a general rule, it is typically better to open the topic to discussion rather than polling with this canned *"everyone vote on **my** choices"* format. Generally you should be able to infer from the conversation and voting what the community wants while still giving everyone a voice. Just my opinion. It's not like we're deciding the fate of mankind here, but [polling is not a good substitute for discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Polling_is_not_a_substitute_for_discussion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site should **OPT-IN** and allow hats.

Comment: +1 (since I cannot upvote my own answer). Seems like a fun promo to get people interacting with the site.

Comment: Actually I'm somewhat without opinion in this case. So lets make an upvote for you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This site should **OPT-OUT** and forbid hats.