# In or Out? Stack Exchange's Winter Bash 2013 Hat Dash

Tags: discussion

Just like [last year](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149/in-or-out-stack-exchanges-winter-bash-2012-hat-dash), do we want to participate in this year's Winter Bash?

> This event will run from 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014. Users
>   will be able to see their entire hat collection at http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com.
>   That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and
>   other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
>   hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
>   available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats
>   will go back into storage.
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be
>   the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

Comment: I agree.Wohoo!!

Comment: I signed us up for it.